# TMPro and phone simulator: Scale font size based on columns of TTF text

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile

I am not entirely sure where to start with this... I am not sure it is even possible.
Basically, I want to emulate old monitors on a mobile phone.

So, the program would detect how big the display is, calculate what font size of my ttf font would be 40 columns, then set all text assets to be whatever that font size is.

Can TMPro do that? I guess I can set font size using HTML tags, so then I could just assign the calculated size to a variable and pass everything in scripting, so that is one approach, but how do I even go about calculating how big a font should be exactly 40 columns, no more no less?

Comment: I did some experimentation. Here is what I found: -- (Using PrintChar21 font) -- Font Size 38, two characters are width 67 (doesn't matter what characters, font is TTF) -- Font Size 39,  two characters are width 69 -- Font Size 40, two characters are width 70 -- Font Size 41, two characters are width 72 -- Font Size 42, two characters are width 74 -- Font Size 42, three characters are width 111 -- It seems pretty consistent, but that outlier between 39, 40, and 41 worries me. Any idea why it is different there?

Comment: Maybe I am making this too hard?
Could it be as simple as setting a TMPro text box to expand to the screenwidth, setting it to autosize the text, print the number of colums I want, then detect the font size and use that to set the rest of my text?

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect how large a font you need to have a fixed number of colums:

- TMPro text box expand to width of the screen.
- Set the TMPro text box to have "Auto Size".
- print as many characters to the screen as you want to have columns. (make sure to use TTF font)
- Force a Mesh Update. (very important!)
- Detect the size of the font with TextMeshProUGUI.fontSize

Boom. Now you know the font size that will make that many columns. Store the value and use as you wish.

Here is example code:

```
    //TextMeshProUGUI Screen_Sizing_String is my TMPro field that stretches accross the whole panel;
    RectTransform _myScreen = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    _myScreen.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Horizontal, Screen.width);
    _myScreen.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Vertical, 0.73f * Screen.width);
    Screen_Sizing_String.ForceMeshUpdate();
    float FontSize = Screen_Sizing_String.fontSize;
```